# Basic kinematics task with falling point equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

> Suppose the equation of falling point has form of:
> $$
> \frac{dv}{dt} = g - kv^2
> $$
>
> - Calculate the terminal velocity
> - Determine the relation between time and velocity

---

I'm taking an introduction to physics course and this is a task that was "left to a reader".

The second one is a separable ODE which can be calculated using usual ODE tactics. I wasn't able to do the first task and I'm clueless. I appreciate your help.

Comment: If you found $v(t)$, the terminal velocity is its limit as $t\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminal velocity is achieved when the net force (and thus acceleration) is zero.

Comment: So, since $v'(t) = a(t)$ and $v'(t) = g - kv^2$, using your clue I just set $0 = g - kv^2$ and get that terminal velocity is $v = \sqrt{g/k}$?

Comment: Yes. An equivalent way is: $$ma=mg-Dv^2,\qquad ma=0\qquad \implies mg=Dv^2 \\ \implies v=\sqrt{\dfrac{mg}{D}}$$ which is the same as your result for $k=D/m$.